# Pen tool creates a new layer for every stroke

Tags: vector, pen-tool, corel-painter

When I make a stroke using the pen tool in Corel Painter 2018, a new layer is automatically generated. I found no apparent way to fix it. Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Corel Painter, however as in other similar applications, the "Pen Tool" is used for making vectors, which are different from normal strokes you would make with the Brush tool.

The Corel Painter documentation on the Pen tool is [here](http://product.corel.com/help/Painter/540213829/Main/EN/Win-Documentation/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=Corel-Painter-Drawing-lines-and-curves.html)

What this means is that each vector path you make with the Pen tool is a separate object with a stroke and fill. Each of these generates its own layer, so that the object is still editable.  This is normal and how the tool is supposed to work.  It works similarly in other applications which also have a Pen tool.

If you don't want that to happen, then perhaps ultimately, the Pen tool is not what you really need.  Perhaps you would be better using the Brush tool to paint with.

Also note that when you export your art as a JPEG or PNG, when you have finished creating your work, all the vector layers in your Corel document will be flattened and rasterized anyway.

Comment: I draw with the brush tool only. My purpose of using vector was to make a stock background that could be purposely enlarged or shrinked without quality loss for different workflows. This would help me to template my work for different purposes before actually converting to raster (or that was the original idea)

Comment: @SantulanChaubey - then perhaps you should just group all the vector layers - then you can move them as one, or rescale them as one.

Answer (score 0):

The Pen brushes should not operate like this, but several of the specialized brushes introduced in Corel Painter 2018, such as the Think Paint tool do create new layers. When messing around with random brushes, it's not uncommon for my to wind up with a half a dozen new layers as I switch types.

I currently have Corel Painter 2019 installed, but switching to the 2018 brushes, these categories seem to start their own layer if you switch to them, or to another one (other than, perhaps, erasers):

- Liquid Ink
- Thick Paint
- Real Watercolor
- Watercolor

Also, in some of the categories, there will be watercolor, ink, etc brushes that create this effect.